# How to use the new feature Presence?

Tags: phoenix-framework

As Phoenixframework verison 1.2 has not yet released, I am searching for any examples about using the new feature of Presence using 1.2rc1

How to detect if a user has turned into offline? to get his current connection status? online or offline?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Phoenix.Presence docs are available here: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.2.0-rc.1/Phoenix.Presence.html

You can always follow the [hexdocs](http://hexdocs.pm) convention of `http://hexdocs.pm/<package>/<version>/<module>.html` to find what you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it does help, yes :)